# Nginx RTMP-module Stat Issue

Tags: nginx, module, rtmp

I am using the nginx rtmp-module from here: https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module and there is an addition to have a stats page, well when I add it properly and go to the url like they show in the documentation, I just get a blank page. Is there anything that I am doing wrong or is there something else that I need to type into the usl besides /stat?

Here is my http portion of my nginx conf for more information:

```
http {
server {
    listen 80;
    location /stat {

        rtmp_stat all;

        rtmp_stat_stylesheet stat.xsl;
    }

    location /stat.xsl {
        root /usr/local/ngnix/html;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If anyone happens to stumble upon this old post, I had the same problem.
The solution was to change:

`rtmp_stat_stylesheet stat.xsl;` to  `rtmp_stat_stylesheet /stat.xsl;`

This worked for me with version nginx-rtmp 1.1.4, nginx 1.4.6.
I believe reasoning for the added `/` is due to the non-standard root location for the html.  If you do not prepend the stat.xsl with the `/` then the dynamically generated stats page will look for the stats.xsl stylesheet in `http://<domain>/stat/stat.xsl`

Answer (score 1):

You will need to copy the stat.xsl to the location "/usr/local/ngnix/html;"